# Why doesn't "x=5 echo ${x}" output anything?

Tags: shell, sh

I am currently trying to familiarise myself with shell line and command execution.

Could anybody explain to me the following behaviour? Why does shell only register an assignment variable when there is a separator before the command? Can assignment not be made in the same command?

```
sh-3.2$ x=5 echo ${x}


sh-3.2$ x=5; echo ${x}

5

sh-3.2$ x=5 && echo ${x}

5
```

Answer (score 0):

When you don't have the separator, you're setting `x` as an *environment* variable while `echo` runs (only for the duration of that single command), *without* defining a shell variable for use in evaluating expansions before the command is started (which is what's happening in the `x=5; echo "$x"` case).

However, `echo` doesn't change its output based on which environment variables are defined (except sometimes very specific environment variables intended to modify its behavior -- `POSIXLY_CORRECT` and the like), so this has no visible effect.